# what is the meaning of (=>) = (,)?

Tags: elm

In the [mouse drag](http://elm-lang.org/examples/drag) example in Elm have defined `(=>) = (,)` so that a list is defined this way:

```
style [ "background-color" => "#67BF46"    , "cursor" => "move" ]
```

I am more accustomed to:

```
style [ ( "background-color" , "#67BF46" ) , ( "cursor" , "move" ) ]
```

are these equivalent?  This looks more like a [record](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#records) to me, but not even that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. That library is merely defining an infix function `=>` they deem prettier than using tuple syntax.

Comment: You can say it is like an alias like in bash